# Using SCNView.prepare() causes crash when using SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, exc-bad-access

I have a `SceneKit` view that uses nodes with different types of `diffuse contents`. One of types is `SKScene`. Before adding such a node, I am running `prepare` function on other `OperationQueue` to have node prepared without shuttering before it's added. It works fine with all other nodes, but when I use `SKScene` as diffuse content, then I get a crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `prepare` function.

```
private class AddNodeOperation: Operation {
    private let node:   SCNNode
    private let parent: SCNNode
    private let arView: AugmentedRealityViewWithSceneView

    init(node: SCNNode, parent: SCNNode, arView: AugmentedRealityViewWithSceneView) {
        self.node   = node
        self.parent = parent
        self.arView = arView
    }

    override func main() {
        arView.sceneView.prepare(node) { isCancelled }
        guard isCancelled == false else { return }
        parent.addChildNode(node)
    }
}
```

Last thing on the operation stack is

> SceneKit`C3DSceneGetAnimationManager:
>
> ->  0x19f013694 <+0>: ldr    x0, [x0, #0x48]
>
> 0x19f013698 <+4>: ret

If I skip running `arView.sceneView.prepare(node) { isCancelled }` then there is no problem.

Can this be resolved somehow?

Comment: What does `arView.sceneView.prepare(node)` do? You'll want to make sure you don't do any `UIKit` view updates (adding subviews, setting view properties, etc.) from a background thread as `UIKit` updates must be performed on the main thread.

Comment: prepare is a SCNView function that prepares node to display before it's added to the scene. This way we can add complicated node without dropping frame rate. This code is run from other thread by design, but I also tested it on main thread. All this functions are SceneKit related, not UIKit.

Comment: That's fine, but It seems like the problem is actually in `arView.sceneView.prepare(node)`; as you say, you can comment it out and the crash no longer occurs. You should probably post that code.

Comment: What does the console say once the crash happens?

Comment: There is nothing interesting in console. I just made a simple project with just this code for preparing and adding node with `SKScene` as `diffuse contents`. Still the same error. I guess this might be some error in `SDK`, because only using `SKScene` causes this.

Comment: looks like you are having threading problems.  You are accessing some variable on a different thread that another thread is trying to access